# Vector filed where all vectors are looking to origin (0, 0)

Tags: vector, field, trigonometry, heading

I have a squared vector field, let's say, x: -256, 256 and y: -256, 256.
All vectors should be pointed to the origin.

I have tried to calculate angle between x,y and origin, to calculate angle as 
atan2(y, x) or atan(y / y) or even using heading calculation (it's illustrated below), but without any success.

[image]

Need something like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more about math than programming.

Comment: Disagree with you, as long first illustration is Processing PVector.heading() or PVector.heading2D() methods.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

atan2(-x, -y) towards origin
atan2(x, y) opposite to origin